# How to get WiX Bootstrapper to run the MSI's maintenance UI Dialog INSTEAD OF the bootstrapper's maintenance UI Dialog

Tags: user-interface, wix, bootstrapper, wix3.11, maintenance-mode

I currently have a WiX MSI project with several features.  This MSI is wrapped in a wix standard Bootstrapper Application bundle project as I need to install several prerequisites. The Installation works great, the right dialogs are used and I can select/install any of the features or all perfectly.  The issue arises when I rerun the installer, or use the change option in add/remove programs.  Instead of launching the MSI's maintenance dialog, it is running the bootstrapper's maintenance UI dialog.  This means that there is no option to modify the installation to install other features that might not have been installed originally.  All I get are options for repair, uninstall and cancel.

[image: Bootstrapper maintenance UI]

What I need is for the proper "Mondo" maintenance ui dialog to be use do I can modify the features installed.  Can someone please advise how can I force the bootstrapper to run the MSI's maintenance UI instead?!?

I have used the following tags in the MSIPackage element in the bootstrapper:
Cache="always" EnableFeatureSelection="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes"

I use UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" in the MSI to reference the mondo dialog set.

If I install just the MSI, I get the Mondo maintenance ui dialog, with options to modify the installation:

[image: MSI Mondo UI maintenance UI Dialog]

when I install the Bootstrapper .exe which includes that same MSI, I get the bootstrapper maintenance UI dialog, which is missing the option to modify the installation ( As shown in the original post).
I'm at a loss, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WixStdBA in WiX v3 never shows internal UI except during initial install.

WiX v4 has an new BA that has more control for showing internal UI.

Comment: Thanks Bob!  Pretty cool to have someone at your level with WiX reply!  It's unfortunate that this is true of v3, but I'll see if we can either live with it for now, or allocate time for the upgrade.  I know there is an upgrade tool, but it had mixed results for me last time I tried it on a smaller, simpler project.  I'll at least run the upgrade tool against it in a separate sandbox and see what comes of it.  Thanks again!

Comment: If the converter doesn't convert, we want to know about it.